# regexp to remove anchor with specific class and it's content?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

```
<a class="rsswidget" href="http:/domain.com/feed/" title="RSS">
<img style="border:0" width="14" height="14" src="http://domain.com/images/rss.png" alt="RSS">
</a>
```

What regexp do I need to get rid of this entire anchor, inclusiveley the image inside?
Unfortunately I'm a regexp noob and so I need your help. Thank you very much.

```
return preg_replace('#<a+class="rsswidget"[^>]*>.*?</a>#is', '', $content);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace UL tags with specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804339/replace-ul-tags-with-specific-class) - dont let the title fool you. Same problem, same solution. It's only the arguments that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's almost right. But the `+` quantifies only the `a`. You wanted to use `[^>]+` at that position:

```
preg_replace('#<a[^>]+class="rsswidget"[^>]*>.*?</a>#is',
```

To avoid any regex-for-html-whatever-downvoting, this would be the [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) alternative:

```
return qp($html)->find("a.rsswidget")->remove()->writeHTML();
```